# Bug Identification: what type of bug is this small ant-like bug?

Tags: species-identification

It's not an ant; do you know what it's called? Found some in the building different times. 
[image]

**Edit:** Size is 4mm (length) x 1mm (height)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a ground beetle (family [Carabidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_beetle))

Comment: Thanks for the quick identification! looked up ground beetle sizes and found: ground beetles are from 1/8inch (3.1 mm) to 1/2inch (12.7 mm); though I haven't seen any quite as long (12.7 mm); perhaps these are baby ground beetles then.

Comment: Baby beetles are not small versions of adult beetles as beetles undergo complete matemorphosis (more info [there](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2701/why-does-the-butterfly-have-a-cocoon-stage-in-its-life-cycle/2779#2779)). There are about 40,000 species of [ground beetles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_beetle). If you only see individuals that are relatively small it just mean that the species that you often see is a relatively small species of ground beetle.

Comment: This isn't a ground beetle; the lack of focus makes any identification uncertain, but my best guess is one of the grain beetles (family Silvanidae); if any have been seen since this question was asked, you probably should try to get rid of them -- they're after stuff in your pantry.

Comment: Are Silvanidae differentiated from Carabidae by having clubbed antenna tips rather than straight? If so I tend to agree.